# Should I use QtObject or var as an (intermediate) "model" property type?

Tags: qt, qml, var

When wrapping e.g. ListView and other things in a component, I usually do this:

```
Item
{
    property QtObject list_model: cpp_list_model

    CustomListView { model: list_model }
}
```

This construct allows me to e.g. use the outer item only in a case where list_model is a context property and just use CustomListView directly if it is instantiated inside other QML.

My colleague says I should rather use `var` instead of `QtObject`, because some things like `ListModel` aren't `QtObject`s per se. Is there a case for this or should I just keep using `QtObject` because there's no `QVariant` involved in that case?

Comment: You could use `alias` instead, so you can make sure, you have the same types as in the `CustomListView`. `property alias list_model: myCustomListView.model`.

Comment: @derM Sorry, my example was unclear. I modified it to include a C++ set context property, `cpp_list_model`, so an alias here won't work as far as I can tell?

Comment: I am pretty sure that `ListModel` is a QObject derived class on the C++ side, but you would need `var` if the model can also be a plain number, string list, etc.

Comment: Ah, I get it! Your colleague is right on his point: A model is not per se an `QtObject`. It might for example be an `int`. I would not recommend using context properties in the declarations, but set them once you instanciate them. Use a dummy-value for your property, so you can test your object with qmlscene

Comment: @derM what do you mean by "set them once instanciate them"? I don't want to load the QML twice, nor do I want any "blabla property undefined" warnings in the log.

Comment: Why do you wrap them ? Do you do it like in your example (just with an outer `Item` that does nothing), or does the `Item` wrapper does more stuff ?

Comment: @GrecKo I wrap them because the inner Component/Item/Whatever is used from QML and directly in a QQuickWidget. In the former case, context properties are not set and instead the corresponding properties are set from QML in varying ways, in the latter case they are set directly from context properties. To catch these "cpp_* undefined" warnings/errors, I need a wrapper in the second case. Unless you can show me a better way of course.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create another component file with your c++ context if you don't want to set your `model` property from c++ ? (I would prefer doing it from c++ here if you instantiates the qml component from c++ anyway.)

Instead of wrapping in an `Item` create a qml file with this content :

```
CustomListView {
    model: cpp_list_model
}
```

With this simpler method you don't have a dummy `Item` wrapper preventing you to easily access the geometry and properties of your ListView.